# Getting output of command '&'

Tags: shell

```
res=$(grunt qunit) & spinner
echo "$res"
```

`spinner` is a function that does spinning animation.

Now I am not getting the output in `echo`.

If I remove `& spinner`, then it works perfectly.

Comment: & is used to execute in background, while && is useful to execute several commands in same line. Is possible that you need to execute `res=$(grunt qunit) && spinner` instead a single &?

Comment: @AlexGalera Then the spinner animation doesn't happen.

Comment: @AlexGalera solved it. by placing that task on another shell file and then calling animation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something more like:

```
spinner &
sppid=$!
res=$(grunt qunit)
kill $sppid
echo "$res"
```

Start the spinner in the background.
Get the processID of your spinner.
Run your command.
Kill the spinner.
Show Results.

Comment: Spinner isn't showing like this.
How i did was Putting the grunt process into another file shell script and then run spinner of the bash command that way i got the output  as well as animation.
Thanks though :D